# NoElementException in java

Tags: java, exception, java.util.scanner

```
int selection;
    while (true) {
        selection = printing();
        if (selection == 4) {

            id = starting();

            if (id < 1 || id > 10) {
                if (id == -20150901) {
                    System.out.println("Exit code entered");
                    break;
                }

                id = incorrectId(id);
            }
        }


    }


public static int printing(){
    Scanner sc = new Scanner(System.in);
    System.out.print("Main menu\n1: check balance\n2: withdraw\n3: deposit\n4: exit\nEnter a choice: ");
    System.out.print("Enter a choice: ");
    int selection = sc.nextInt();
    return selection;
}
```

This is part of my java code.
The NoElementException occured in the third line.
If the whole code is needed, I will copy and paste here and explain what it is about.
How can I solve this exception?
I want to get keyboard input every time the loop starts.

Thank you.

Comment: _Which_ third line, the top, or the `main()` method?  Have you poked around here on SO for help on this problem before posting your question?

Comment: `nextInt()` throws a `NoSuchElementException` "if input is exhausted", according to the spec. So your standard input must be empty. What is the standard input to your program?

Answer (score 0):

Your code creates a new Scanner wrapping `System.in` each time you call `printing()`.  This is incorrect.  Instead, your application should create exactly one `Scanner` wrapping `System.in`, save it somewhere, and reuse it for each `printing()` call and all other places where you are reading from `System.in`.

The problem with creating multiple `Scanner` objects is that that the `hashNext*` and `next*` methods can cause characters to be "read ahead" characters into the Scanner's buffer.  So the first `printing()` could "consume" all characters.

---

Now this may not be the actual cause of your problem.  Other possible causes could be:

- standard input could be empty, or
- you may be (directly or indirectly) closing the `System.in` in some other part of the code.

However, the problem I identified is a bug that *would* cause application failures in other contexts ... and it is advisable to understand and fix it.

Comment: Thank you. I tried to put Scanner sc = new Scanner(System.in); just after the class declaration, then the problem occured: cannot be referenced from a static context. So I changed static to default. Then the main could not resolve the methods.....

Comment: You need to review your lecture notes on what `static` means and how static and instance variables work.  A static *variable* can be accessed from a static method or an instance method.  An instance variable can only be referenced from an instance method if you tell the compiler *which instance you are talking about*.